# separate file and path in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, path

How can I separate the path and file elements in a bash loop like this?

```
for file in `find /my/path -name "*.ext"`
do
    #(path,onlyfile) = separate_path_and_file $file
    #dosomethingwith $onlyfile
done
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't. But you can do them separately.

```
$ foo=/usr/local/bin/bar
$ echo "${foo##*/}"
bar
$ echo "${foo%/*}"
/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: How to get name of directory on `basename $(dirname $(dirname $DEVPATH))`?

Answer (score 30):

I would suggest [`dirname`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) and [`basename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename):

```
for file in `find /my/path -name "*.ext"`
do
    path="$(dirname "$file")"
    onlyfile="$(basename "$file")"
    # ...
done
```

Comment: This is much more readable than the accepted answer.

Comment: and in case there are spaces in the file, i would add quotation around the $file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194192/basename-with-spaces-in-a-bash-script

Comment: In `zsh` of Windows Subsystem for Linux, `path="$(dirname $file)"` will change `$PATH`, then `onlyfile="$(basename $file)"` will print error `basename: command not found`

Comment: I corrected the wrong quoting. It needs to be `path=$(dirname "$file")`. Not `path="$(dirname $file)"` which breaks on spaces. But there is still the problem of the `for` loop which will also break on spaces.